# Minkowski metric. Scalar or tensor?

Tags: clifford-algebras

The defining property for the gamma matrices to generate a Clifford algebra is the anticommutation relation

$\displaystyle\{ \gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu \} = \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu = 2 \eta^{\mu \nu} I_4 $

where $\{ , \}$ is the anticommutator, $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ is the Minkowski metric with signature (+ − − −) and $I_4$ is the 4 × 4 identity matrix.

This makes perfect sense if $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ is a scalar that is equal to zero when $\mu \neq \nu$ and is either +1  or -1 when they are the same. This would make sense because squaring a gamma matrix results in either $I_4$  or $-I_4$

But everything I read online says that $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ is a tensor

$\eta^{\mu \nu} = \pm \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix},$

Just for reference the 4 gamma matrices are:

$\begin{align}
\gamma^0 &= \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 &  0 &  0 \\
  0 & 1 &  0 &  0 \\ 
  0 & 0 &  -1 &  0 \\
  0 & 0 &  0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},\quad&
\gamma^1 &= \begin{pmatrix}
   0 &  0 & 0 & 1 \\
   0 &  0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  -1 &  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\
\gamma^2 &= \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
   0 & 0 & i &  0 \\
   0 & i & 0 &  0 \\
  -i & 0 & 0 &  0
\end{pmatrix},\quad&
\gamma^3 &= \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 1 &  0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  -1 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 &  0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}$

Comment: Well. $A$ is a matrix but its entries are real numbers.

Comment: You can in fact work out that if $\mu \neq \nu$ that the right hand side yields zero. and you can work out that it will yield the diagonal components of $\eta$ for when the indices are the same. Obviously the object on the right depends on the indices of the objects on the left (there are two indices that describe the pieces so we know it is an array at least which is definitely not a scalar)

Comment: multiplying 2 gamma matrices results in $I$ or $-I$ not $\eta^{\mu \nu}$

Comment: The thing is you are looking at it component-wise, that is the key thing here, for a given pair of indices the equation is completely true

Comment: Take for instance $\mu=1,\nu=2$ and apply $\gamma^1 \gamma^2 + \gamma^2 \gamma^1 = \gamma^1 \gamma^2 - \gamma^1 \gamma^2 = 2 \eta^{12} I = 0I$

Comment: But thats what I just said. $\eta^{1 2} = 0 = scalar$ This makes perfect sense if $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ is a scalar that is equal to zero when $\mu \neq \nu$ and is either +1  or -1 when they are the same. This would make sense because squaring a gamma matrix results in either $I_4$  or $-I_4$

Comment: Well yeah, the components of $\eta$ are in fact scalars, this is a set of 16 equations for the individual components of the matrix that represents $\eta$, this is what you are not seeing. Another thing to note is that $\gamma^{\mu}$ is a vector of matrices

Comment: I know how tensors work

Comment: So what is $\eta^{1 1}$

Comment: $\eta^{11}$ is the first component of the metric tensor, the above formula yields $2 \gamma^1 \gamma1 = 2 I_4 \Rightarrow \eta^{11} = 1$. But that's fine because the components of the minkowski metric are numbers. But realize that there are 16 such components, obviously $\eta$ cannot be a scalar as a scalar has one component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\eta= \pm \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix},$

but $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ is just one component of $\eta$